# Python Doc to PDF converting using

Tags: python, python-docx, aspose.words, comtypes, docx2pdf

I am trying to convert a document .docx to .pdf
So I tried to use docx2pdf and comtypes then aspose.words

my code is simple:

```
from docx2pdf import convert
def openfile():
    convert('Xp_Tank.docx','output/XpTank.pdf')
openfile()
```

and the other code is:

```
import win32com.client
def convert2():
    wdFormatPDF = 17
    inputFile = os.path.abspath("Xp_Tank.docx")
    outputFile = os.path.abspath("output/XpTank2.pdf")
    word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(inputFile)
    doc.SaveAs(outputFile, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
    doc.Close()
    word.Quit()
convert2()
```

also I tried with:

```
import comtypes.client
def newpdf():
    wdFormatPDF = 17
    inputFile = os.path.abspath("Xp_Tank.docx")
    outputFile = os.path.abspath("output/comtypes3.pdf")
    word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(inputFile)
    doc.SaveAs(outputFile, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
    doc.Close()
    word.Quit()
newpdf()
```

But all have the same formatting error! like the image shows:

[image]

SO lastly I converted it with `aspose.words` it works perfectly but it's not a free package!

[image]

Is there another way to correct one of the above codes or is there another way to do that?
Many thanks

Comment: Hi @tibas where did you find [aspose-words](https://pypi.org/project/aspose-words/)  is not a free package

Comment: I said that is not free, and I want an alternative to it.

Comment: @BhavyaParikh Aspose.Words is a commercial package. In the free evaluation mode it has limitations, like injects a watermark and truncated the document to several hundred of paragraphs. Here is the pricing information https://purchase.aspose.com/pricing/words/python-net